# InternalServerErrorException in RestEasy

Tags: java, resteasy

as per resteasy java doc (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/InternalServerErrorException.html) , InternalServerErrorException is thrown by RESTEasy when HTTP Internal Service Error (500) is encountered .Can someone please provide deatil when RESTEasy will encounter 500 error ?

As per my understanding , consumer will get 500 error code in case of app server itself not able to respond due to heavy load so in that case , request itself will not reach to restEasy . Please advice on my understanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resteasy can raise an `InternalServerErrorException` for a multitude of reasons.  It is thrown when anything bad happens on the server side that doesn't have a more specific exception.

Examples of when it is used in Resteasy:

1. Parsing failures in MessageBodyReaders and MessageBodyWriters.
2. Method parameter injection failures.
3. Request dispatching failures
4. Certain OAuth failures